# How to show multiple select options when user select multiple options and when unselect it still hide and reset!!!?? jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel

I have select options contains languages, it's supposedly that user choose multiple options (languages) or an option (language), and i want user when choose an option (language), new select option shows, and contains his level in that language.

when user select multiple languages (english, arabic, france), three select option show, his level in these language, and when unselect any options, it's supposed to, the select option (that contains his level in that language) become hidden and reset (return to default select (first option)).

**but i've some problems in my code**

1- when user select multiple options, multiple select options that contains his level don't show all at once.

2- when user unselect an option it stills show and not reset (return to default select (first option))?!!

could you help me please

**my view blade with script:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
    
        <form>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="languages">Languages</label>
                    <select id="languages" class="form-control" multiple>
                        <option>Choose Language...</option>
                        <option value="1">English</option>
                        <option value="2">Arabic</option>
                        <option value="3">France</option>
                        <option value="4">Espanole</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div id="arabicShow" style="display: none" class="form-row">
                <div id="" class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="arabic">Arabic level</label>
                    <select id="arabic" class="form-control">
                        <option value='' selected>Choose Your level...</option>
                        <option value='' >a</option>
                        <option value=''>b</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="englishShow" style="display: none" class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="english">English level</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option value=''>Choose Your level...</option>
                        <option value='' >a</option>
                        <option value=''>b</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="franceShow" style="display: none" class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="france">France level</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option value=''>Choose Your level...</option>
                        <option value='' >a</option>
                        <option value=''>b</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    
    @stop
    @section('script')
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function (){
                $( "#languages option:first-child" ).attr("disabled","disabled");
                $( "#arabic option:first-child" ).attr("disabled","disabled");
                $( "#english option:first-child" ).attr("disabled","disabled");
                $( "#france option:first-child" ).attr("disabled","disabled");

                $('#languages').change(function(){
                    var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text().trim(); //get text
                    if(text === "Arabic"){
                        $('#arabicShow').show();
                 
                    }else if(text === "English"){
                        $('#englishShow').show();
                    }else if(text === "France"){
                    $('#franceShow').show();
                }else {
                        $('#arabicShow').hide();
                        $('#englishShow').hide();//hide
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    
    @stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through all selected options and then depending on condition show require select-boxes.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#languages option:first-child").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $("#arabic option:first-child").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $("#english option:first-child").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $("#france option:first-child").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $('.selects').hide(); //hide all
  $('#languages').change(function() {
    $('.selects select:not(:visible)').val(""); //reset 
    $('.selects').hide(); //hide all
    //loop through all selected options..
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text()
      if (text === "Arabic") {
        $('#arabicShow').show();
      } else if (text === "English") {
        $('#englishShow').show();
      } else if (text === "France") {
        $('#franceShow').show();
      }
    })

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="languages">Languages</label>
      <select id="languages" class="form-control" multiple>
        <option>Choose Language...</option>
        <option value="1">English</option>
        <option value="2">Arabic</option>
        <option value="3">France</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--added one common class i.e : selects-->
  <div id="arabicShow" class="form-row selects">
    <div id="" class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="arabic">Arabic level</label>
      <select id="arabic" class="form-control">
        <option value='' selected>Choose Your level...</option>
        <option value=''>a</option>
        <option value=''>b</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="englishShow" class="form-row selects">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="english">English level</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value=''>Choose Your level...</option>
        <option value=''>a</option>
        <option value=''>b</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="franceShow" class="form-row selects">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="france">France level</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value=''>Choose Your level...</option>
        <option value=''>a</option>
        <option value=''>b</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works but there is two issues: 
1- when i add common class as (selects) to hide all (divs) at once, and remove (display: none) from divs as you say, all (divs) still show i have to set (display: none) .
2- when user select (language) and select his level, then unselect it, the value of his level still keep selcted, i want reset it to the first option when unselect it or when the select option return to hide, the value return to first option.

Comment: Thanks alot, i'll mark as answer, but i've the same issue, for example:
when user select (english) and (arabic) then choose his level (a) for english, and (b) for arabic, then unselect (arabic), his level (select) hides but still store value (b), i want reset it as soon as unselect it, because when i store data by Request into DB it returns the value(b) that he unselected, it should has no value because it hide!?

Comment: Your other options inside select-box also have `value=""` why ? In above code you can see it set 1st option selected but , there are other options which also statisfy this conditon ie : `.val("")` so i think problem is there .

Comment: So , instead of `$('.selects select:not(:visible)').val("");` try `$('.selects select:not(:visible) option:first').prop("selected",true);`.

Comment: i'll try and tell u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233056/discussion-between-mahmoud-diab-and-swati).